# When a match is found, the whole cell is shown highlighted, but only the text found will be replaced in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice

I want to replace the whole cell, can someone help?

For example, searching for **htmlPath** will highlight a cell containing **"htmlPath":"F:\amazon_mp3\1/1053",**, and replacing with **},** will leave the cell containing "},":"F:\amazon_mp3\1/1053",.

Comment: Have you tried using wildcards?

Comment: yes, but its not working.